# viewmodel in app delegate ion mmvm in swift

Tags: ios

I am doing in mvvm .

my code as below:-

private var url = URL(string: "http://www.example.com")!
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]

```
class Webservice{

    static func fetchHostels(completion: @escaping ([JSONDictionary]) -> ()) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

            if let data = data {

                let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                let dictionaries = json as! [JSONDictionary]
                completion(dictionaries)
            }

            }.resume()

}
}
```

My hostelmodel:-

class hostelmodel: NSObject {

```
var name: String?
var city: String?

init(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String, let location = dictionary["location"] as? [String: Any], let city = location["city"] as? String {
        self.name = name
        self.city = city
    }
}
```

}

my hostelviewmodel:-

```
 class hostelviewmodel: NSObject {




  private var hostels: [hostelmodel] = []

    func fetchData(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        Webservice.fetchHostels { [weak self] dictionaries in
            self?.hostels = dictionaries.flatMap(hostelmodel.init)
            completion?()
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections() -> Int {
        //your number of section
        return 1
    }

    func numberOfRows() -> Int {
        //your number of rows
        return hostels.count
    }

    func hostel(atIndex index: Int) -> hostelmodel {
        return hostels[index]
    }
}


my hostellist:-


    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private var viewModel: hostelviewmodel

    init(hostelViewModel: hostelviewmodel) {
        self.viewModel = hostelViewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData()
    }


    private func fetchData() {
        viewModel.fetchData { [weak self] in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return viewModel.numberOfSections()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.numberOfRows()
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as! QM_RestaurtantCell

    cell.setRestaurtantData(restaurtant: QM_RestaurtantModel)

    return cell
    }




}
}
```

my hosteltablecell:-

```
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var city: UILabel!




    func setRestaurtantData(restaurtant:hostelmodel)
    {
        self.name.text = restaurtant.name
        self.city.text = restaurtant.city

    }



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I am doing without storyboard, so here how to set in the appdelegate. What  should I set as root view controller in app delegate class. And also how the name and city value display in the tableview cell for row index in swift.How to deo

Comment: Yes, there's not only one problem. Your code has many issues. Will post refactored code soon.

Comment: First - you should capitalize class names, like - HostelViewModel,
lowercase first letters - for variables names e.g.:
let hostelViewModel = HostelViewModel()

Comment: can u explain how to do

Comment: I posted answer here with edited code. Try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

For Migrating to App Delegate to your HostelList View Controller :

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Transferring Control to First Controller

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let nav1 = UINavigationController()
        let vc = HostelList()
        nav1.viewControllers = [vc]
        window?.rootViewController = vc
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()        
        return true
    }
```

To set your values in tableview, Use this function :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 }
```

Comment: showing an error as cannot invoke initializer for type HostelList with no arguments.How to solve this.  In this did we need to call the view controller or the view model.Then how to do cellfor row in tableview

Comment: inside what should give the code .I have already written a func in the hosteltablecell,so how to call that,can u help to solve this problem

Comment: you should call cellForRow in class that is datasource for your tableview.
Show your viewController code also pls

Comment: @AntonNovoselov i have already given in the question class name is hostellist.And also how to call in app delegate .

Comment: Where do you call cellForRowAtIndexPath? Can't find it in your code.
How do you set delegate and datasource for your tableView?

Comment: @AntonNovoselov  i have upload my code.please check

Answer (score -1):

Ok. Try this refactored code pls:
**AppDelegate didFinish:**
func application(_ application: UIApplication,

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let vm = HostelViewModel()

        let vc = HostelViewController(hostelViewModel: vm)

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = vc
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

**HostelViewController:**

```
class HostelViewController: UIViewController {

    private let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)

    private var viewModel: HostelViewModel

    init(hostelViewModel: HostelViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = hostelViewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createUI()

        tableView.dataSource = viewModel

        fetchData()
    }

    func createUI() {
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.register(HostelCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


        let tableViewConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
        ]


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(tableViewConstraints)
    }

    private func fetchData() {
        viewModel.fetchData { [weak self] in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**HostelViewModel:**

```
class HostelViewModel: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    private var hostels: [HostelModel] = []

    func fetchData(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        Webservice.fetchHostels { [weak self] dictionaries in
            self?.hostels = dictionaries.flatMap(HostelModel.init)
            completion?()
        }
    }

    func hostel(atIndex index: Int) -> HostelModel {
        return hostels[index]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hostels.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let hostel = hostels[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HostelCell

        cell.setRestaurtantData(restaurtant: hostel)

        return cell

    }
}
```

**HostelCell file:**

```
let cellIdentifier = "HostelTableCell"

class HostelCell: UITableViewCell {

    private var name: UILabel = UILabel()
    private var city: UILabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        createUI()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func setRestaurtantData(restaurtant: HostelModel)
    {
        self.name.text = restaurtant.name
        self.city.text = restaurtant.city

    }

    func createUI() {

        [city, name].forEach {
            contentView.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        }

        city.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        city.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        name.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        name.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

**HostelModel:**

```
class HostelModel {

    var name: String?
    var city: String?

    init(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String, let location = dictionary["location"] as? [String: Any], let city = location["city"] as? String {
            self.name = name
            self.city = city
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but now still showing error as :-missing argument for parameter #1 in call in the line -  let vm = HostelViewModel()  .HOW TO SOLVE

Comment: Did you copy pasted my code exactly? I have compiled this code in Xcode and it's compiled ok.

Comment: You should copy paste HosteViewModel code as I posted

Comment: how is it going? I've just edited HostelCell code, there's changes in func createUI()